# can't rename environment rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

I haven't named properly my rails' environments : local instead of development and development instead of staging.
I am now trying to rename them. I have changed the names in my `database.yml`, `secret.yml` and `application.yml`. I have also renamed the files in the environment folder properly.
But when I try to push my code to my staging environment, I get :
         `remote: ###### WARNING:
 remote:        You are deploying to a non-production environment: "development".`
Whereas it should be staging. Does anyone know how to rename an environment?

Answer (score 0):

**Environment Variables**

From the [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-environment-settings):

> `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` defines the Rails environment (production,
>   development, test, and so on) that Rails will run under.

The environment of your app should be set with the [*environment variables*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) on your system.

Environment variables are variables stored in the OS of your system. Accessing them depends on which system you're using; they can mostly be set from the command line:

```
$ export RAILS_ENV="staging"
```

In Heroku, you can set what they call "config" vars (they're really environment vars) in the `settings` pane for your app:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working. I'll upvote you when I'll be able :) (soon)

Comment: Nice, good to hear it's working! I think you can accept the answer by clicking the tick underneath the votes part.